# Require second user confirmation on Windows 10 login?

Tags: windows-10, login

I would like to setup a laptop in my daughters room, but I only want her to use it when she is allowed. Is it possible to make her login wait for confirmation before actually logging her in? Is it possible to enable 2FA login for Windows that use a mobile device for the second factor?

Answer (score 1):

See the Microsoft article
[How to use two-step verification with your Microsoft account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12408/microsoft-account-how-to-use-two-step-verification).
As the name says, you will need to logon using a Microsoft account for this option.

In a nutshell, the instructions are:

> - Go to the [Security basics](https://account.microsoft.com/security) page and sign in with your Microsoft account.
> - Select **More security option**s.
> - Under **Two-step verification**, choose **Set up two-step verification** to turn it on, or choose **Turn off two-step
>     verification** to turn it off.
> - Follow the instructions.
>
> Note
>
> As part of setting up this account, you’ll be given a QR code to scan
>   with your device; this is one way we ensure you are in physical
>   possession of the device you are installing the Authenticator app to.